An Extra pair of curly braces is coming using JSR223 post processor with groovy
We are using a JSR223 code to make an json object using below code,
def mandatory = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).Properties.Room.Extras.findAll { extra -> extra.IsMandatory }

def payload = []
mandatory.each { extra ->
    def item = [:]
    item.put('ExtraId', extra.ExtraId)
    item.put('OptionId', extra.Options[0].OptionId)
    item.put('ExpectedNetCost', extra.Options[0].NetCost)
    payload.add(item)
}

vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([Extras: payload]).toPrettyString())

we are using 'toPrettyString' as well but still getting an extra pair of curly braces (at the start and end).
Can someone please help to remove this !
I have tried this link After updating json file with groovy, the file data contains extra curly brackets and "content" object
but solution doesn't work for me.

If you don't want to have the generated value as a JSON Object you can replace this line:
vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder([Extras: payload]).toPrettyString())

with this line:
vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())

In this case you will have only the JSON Array, to wit your output will be:
[
  {
    "ExtraId": "528",
    "OptionId": "712",
    "ExpectedNetCost": {
      "Amount": 22.0,
      "Currency": "EUR"
    }
  },
  {
    "ExtraId": "529",
    "OptionId": "714",
    "ExpectedNetCost": {
      "Amount": 20.0,
      "Currency": "EUR"
    }
  }
]

More information:

Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON
Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

